# Validation on each class element using javascript and PHP then remove disabled class from the next step button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to achieve validation on each class element. I'm using form which has multiple input with same name attribute. I want to validate each input element.

**This is my HTML**

```
 <input type="text" class="date_of_birth" name="date[]" onkeyup="dateOfBirth('stepbirth')" />
 <span class="stepbirthVal"></span>
 <input type="text" class="date_of_birth" name="date[]" onkeyup="dateOfBirth('stepbirth')" />
 <span class="stepbirthVal"></span>
 <a href="javascript:;" id="stepbirth" class="btn disabled" onclick="kindKompas('stepbirth')">Next Step</a>
```

**How i'm sending values to my PHP script**

```
function dateOfBirth(inputid)
{
  var DoB = [];

    $(".date_of_birth").each(function(){
        DoB.push($(this).val());
    });
  var newDob = DoB.slice(0,-1);
  var stepVar = newDob;

var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
  //GET JSON from Validation.php and extract the nodes
  var response = xmlhttp.responseText;
  var parseJson = JSON.parse(response);
  var resultCode = parseJson.code;
  var resultMessage = parseJson.message;

   //Show Validation Message
   var items = document.getElementsByClassName("stepbirthVal"),
   i, len;
   for (i = 0, len = items.length; i < len; i++) {
   items[i].innerHTML = resultMessage;
   }

   //Style the button

     var element = document.getElementById(inputid);

     if(resultCode == 0)
     {
        element.classList.add("disabled");
     }

     if(resultCode == 1)
     {
        element.classList.remove("disabled");
     }

    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","test.php?q="+stepVar+"&q2="+inputid";
xmlhttp.send();
```

}

When user fill the first input it get validated and remove the disabled class from the button. I check in network how i receive the value when fill only one input field

`test.php?q=20/02/2000&q2=stepbirth`

Which is fine my php script expect the value like this. It gets validated and remove disabled class.

But the issue is when there are more than one input data then i receive values like this

`test.php?q=20/02/2000,03/05/2010&q2=stepbirth`

Then script stops validate, so the disabled class does not remove.

**Here is my php script.**

```
//Get Parameters Passed From the JS Call to This Script
$fieldValue = $_GET["q"];
$fieldName = $_GET["q2"];

//Validate the DOB
if($fieldName == 'stepbirth')
{
    $birthDateLen = strlen($fieldValue);

    if($birthDateLen > 9)
    {
        if (checkBirthDate($fieldValue))
        {
            //

            //Get last 4 characters of the Date for the Year
            $year =  substr($fieldValue, -4);
            if($year > 1900)
            {

                //Get Timestamp passed over
                $dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $fieldValue);
                $userDate = $dt->getTimestamp();

                //Get Date 1 Year from Today
                $yearTime = date(strtotime('+10000 year'));

                //If User's Date is Within 1 Year
                if($userDate < $yearTime)
                {
                    echo '{"code":1,"message":""}';
                }
                else
                {
                    echo '{"code":0,"message":"Fill date to 365 days from now.}';       
                }
            }

        }
        else
        {
            echo '{"code":0,"message":"Please fill valid date of birth."}';
        }
    }

    else
    {
        echo '{"code":0,"message":""}';
    }

}
```

I hope you guys understand my question.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should loop through the comma-delimited list of date strings, validating each one. Here's a mockup of the solution:

```
<?php 

$fieldValue = "20/02/2000,03/05/2010";
$fieldName = "stepbirth";

//Validate the DOB
if ($fieldName == 'stepbirth')
{
    $birthDateLen = strlen($fieldValue);

    if ($birthDateLen > 9)
    {
        foreach (explode(",", $fieldValue) as $dateString) {
            echo $dateString;
            //Get Timestamp passed over
            $dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $dateString);
            //$userDate = $dt->getTimestamp();

            //Get Date 1 Year from Today
            $yearTime = date(strtotime('+10000 year'));

            //Get last 4 characters of the Date for the Year
            $year =  substr($fieldValue, -4);

            if ($year <= 1900)
            {
                echo '{"code":0,"message":""}';
            }
            else if ($userDate < $yearTime)
            {
                //If User's Date is Within 1 Year
                echo '{"code":1,"message":""}';
            }
            else
            {
                echo '{"code":0,"message":"Fill date to 365 days from now.}';       
            }
        }
    }
}
```